# In App Email View doesn't close - iPhone OS 4

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am having difficulties adding the ability for a user to send a support email to myself (the maker of said app).  I have gotten it work almost perfectly however the view doesn't close when you click cancel, or when you click send. Thanks for the help!

Here is the code:

```
 MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];


        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [mail setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"support@lindahlstudios.com"]];
        [mail setSubject:@"Fraction Calculator Lite Support"];    

        [self presentModalViewController:mail animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting `self` to be the MFMailComposeViewController's delegate. In mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error: be sure to call

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

like so:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Can I make something else the delegate so that I do not need the extra method?

Comment: Sure, you can make something else the delegate, but whatever you make the delegate will have to call dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: to hide the view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the delegate method from `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`.

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```